# Google Sheets API V4 and google apps script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been using the Sheets API v4 to allow authorised users enter data into a spreadsheet from a form. What I want to do is have a google apps script trigger a function when ever new data is added. I cant seem to get the on edit trigger to work using

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('makeLog')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}

function makeLog(){
Logger.log("New Entry")
}
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about following sample script? When spreadsheet was edited from outside by Sheet API v4, `onChange()` becomes a trigger for it. So please change from `onEdit()` to `onChange()` for your script. I prepared a sample script I used for testing.

This sample script send an e-mail, when spreadsheet was edited by Sheet API v4. I confirmed that this works fine. When you use this sample, please input your e-mail and run firstly `createSpreadsheetEditTrigger()`. By this, a trigger is installed. After this, edit spreadsheet by Sheet API v4.

When when spreadsheet was edited from outside by Sheet API v4, I used `sendEmail()` as a sample, because script editor is closed.

**Sample script :**

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('makeLog')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onChange()
      .create();
}

function makeLog() {
  MailApp.sendEmail("### Your e-mail address ###", "test mail", "Spreadsheet was edited.");
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? The trigger is on the server. Is there a way to trigger a function on the client side?

Comment: You can use the method of ``newTrigger()`` using Web Apps. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app

Comment: What if its not a web app?

Comment: If it executes methods from outside client, it thinks of web apps and execution api. In the case of installation of triggers, it uses web apps. About this, because I have already confirmed this, don't worry. On the other hand, execution api cannot be done because of the limitation. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api#limitations

Comment: is this possible with python? from service account running code?